# SurveyMonkey API - Closed Survey

Tags: surveymonkey

I'd be grateful for some help with a couple of questions on the Survey Monkey API;

1. Using the API console, I've entered a valid survey number and back got a list of collectors. Is there also an API call to get information about each of the collectors ?
2. Is possible through the API to determine if a survey has been closed ?
3. Is possible through the API to determine if a reponse has been completed ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. With the list of [collectors](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_collector_list), you can get details about the type and the status of the collector (open/close). Please see the above link for a list of optional response fields. Once you have the collector_id, you can pass that to [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list), which will give you details for the respondents AND only those collectors.
2. From that same get_collector routine, you can see if the collector is open or closed. It is an option return field called 'data.collectors[_].open'
3. Using get_respondent_list][4] you can pass those respondent IDs to [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses). Usually the response is recorded if the respondent completes the page or the entire survey.